# Invalid HTML error in google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying out Google Tag Manager for my website and I added my tags to the workspace and hit publish. However I got an error for my jQuery tag (3.1.1, slim/minified). Is stuff like this not supposed to be with google tag manager?

EDIT: I used a custom HTML tag

Tag that I added:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of issue]

Thanks in advance,
Diego

Comment: Google Tag Manager does not support Subresource Integrity attributes. I just read that here, so totally unsupported and I don't know the basis of it: https://www.noisetosignal.io/2016/02/deploying-autotrack-js-through-google-tag-manager/

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround it seems to be possible to append the script with attributes in a custom HTML tag:

```
<script>
  (function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js';  
  script.setAttribute('integrity','sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc=');
  script.setAttribute('crossorigin','anonymous');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  })();
</script>
```

This seems a bit quaint (I would think GTM does asynchronous tag injection in any case) but allows you to set attributes including integrity without complaints. I did not thorough testing, I just changed the hash to see if the attribute does what it's supposed to to and received a message that the resource is blocked - so that seemed to work.

Comment: This fixed the error with tag manager but I get a weird error in my console:  `index.html:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at index.html:41` The $ being a jQuery selector in a document ready function. This could be my implementation though

Comment: I do not get that error, but then I did not make any calls to jQuery functions.  "$ is not defined" often happens when you have set jQuery to "noconflict" mode, maybe that is somehow included in the CDN hosted file.

Comment: Could be something else. If it helps here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/pgdTYS7T)